# Optimize and speed up MySQL query selection

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization, rdbms

I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to optimize my current selection query on a MySQL database.

I have 2 MySQL tables with a relationship **one-to-many**. One is the `user` table that contains the unique list of users and It has around **22krows**.  One is the `linedata` table which contains all the possible coordinates for each user and it has around **490k rows**.

In this case we can assume the **foreign key** between the 2 tables is the `id` value. In the case of the user table the id is also the auto-increment primary key, while in the linedata table it's not primary key cause we can have more rows for the same user.

#### The CREATE STMT structure

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isActive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `userId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21938 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `linedata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `x` float NOT NULL,
  `y` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

#### The selection query

```
SELECT 
        u.id, 
        u.isActive, 
        u.userId,
        u.name,
        u.gender,
        u.age,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(', ',timestamp,x, y)
                     ORDER BY timestamp ASC SEPARATOR '; '
                    ) as linedata_0

        FROM user u 
        JOIN linedata l
        ON u.id=l.id
        WHERE DATEDIFF(l.timestamp, '2018-02-28T20:00:00.000Z') >= 0
          AND DATEDIFF(l.timestamp, '2018-11-20T09:20:08.218Z') <= 0
        GROUP BY userId;
```

#### The EXPLAIN output

```
+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
    |   ID  |   SELECT_TYPE |   TABLE   |   TYPE    |   POSSIBLE_KEYS   |   KEY     |   KEY_LEN     |   REF     |   ROWS    |       EXTRA                                                |
    +-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
    |   1   |   SIMPLE      |   l      |   ALL   |   NULL         |   NULL |      NULL        |   NULL    |   491157   |   "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" |
    +-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
    |   1   |   SIMPLE      |   u      |   eq_ref  |   PRIMARY         |   PRIMARY |      4        |   l.id   |   1       |     NULL                                                   |
    +-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The selection query works if for example I add another WHERE condition for filter single users. Let's say that I want to select just **200** user, then I got around **14 seconds** as execution time. Around **7 seconds** if I select just the first **100 users**. But in case of having only datetime range condition it seems loading without an ending point. Any suggestions?

#### UPDATE

After following the Rick's suggestions now the query benchmark is around 14 seconds. Here below the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

**id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra**
1,PRIMARY,u,index,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,NULL,21959,100.00,NULL
1,PRIMARY,l,ref,id_timestamp_index,id_timestamp_index,4,u.id,14,100.00,"Using index condition"
2,"DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"No tables used"

I have changed a bit some values of the tables:

[image: linedata table]
[image: user table]

Where the `id` in user table can be joined with `userId` in linedata table. And they are integer now. We will have string type just for the userId value in user table cause it is a sort of long string identifier like **0000309ab2912b2fd34350d7e6c079846bb6c5e1f97d3ccb053d15061433e77a_0**.

So, just for make a quick example we will have in `user` and in `linedata`  table:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--------+---+
|   id  | isActive  |   userId  |       name        | gender |age|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--------+---+
|   1   |   1       |  x4by4d   |   john            | m      | 22|
|   2   |   1       |  3ub3ub   |   bob             | m      | 50|
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+--------+---+



+-------+-----------+-----------+------+---+
|   id  | userId    |timestamp  |  x   | y |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+----+
|   1   |   1       | somedate  |  30  | 10 |
|   2   |   1       | somedate  |  45  | 15 |
|   3   |   1       | somedate  |  50  | 20 |
|   4   |   2       | somedate  |  20  |  5 |
|   5   |   2       | somedate  |  25  | 10 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+------+----+
```

I have added a **compound index** made of `userId` and `timestamp` values in linedata table.

Maybe instead of having as primary key an ai id value for `linedata` table, if I add a **composite primary key** made of `userId`+`timestamp`? Should increase the performance or maybe not?

Answer (score 2):

I need to help you fix several bugs before discussing performance.

First of all, `'2018-02-28T20:00:00.000Z'` won't work in MySQL.  It needs to be `'2018-02-28 20:00:00.000'` and something needs to be done about the timezone.

Then, don't "hide a column in a function".  That is `DATEDIFF(l.timestamp ...)` cannot use any indexing on `timestamp`.

So, instead of

```
    WHERE  DATEDIFF(l.timestamp, '2018-02-28T20:00:00.000Z') >= 0
      AND  DATEDIFF(l.timestamp, '2018-11-20T09:20:08.218Z') <= 0
```

do something like

```
    WHERE  l.timestamp >= '2018-02-28 20:00:00.000'
      AND  l.timestamp  < '2018-11-20 09:20:08.218'
```

I'm confused about the two tables.  Both have `id` and `userid`, yet you join on `id`.  Perhaps instead of

```
CREATE TABLE `linedata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  ...
```

you meant

```
CREATE TABLE `linedata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- (the id for `linedata`)
  `userId` int NOT NULL,   -- to link to the other table
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
...
```

Then there could be several `linedata` rows for each `user`.

At that point, this

```
    JOIN  linedata l  ON u.id=l.id
```

becomes

```
    JOIN  linedata l  ON u.id=l.userid
```

Now, for performance: `linedata` needs `INDEX(userid, timestamp)` - in that order.

Now, think about the output.  You are asking for up to 22K rows, with possibly hundreds of "ts,x,y" strung together in one of the columns.  What will receive this much data?  Will it choke on it?

And `GROUP_CONCAT` has a *default* limit of 1024 bytes.  That will allow for about 50 points.  If a 'user' can be in more than 50 spots in 9 days, consider increasing `group_concat_max_len` before running the query.

To make it work even faster, reformulate it this way:

```
SELECT  u.id, u.isActive, u.userId, u.name, u.gender, u.age,
        ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(', ',timestamp, x, y)
                      ORDER BY timestamp ASC
                      SEPARATOR '; ')
        ) as linedata_0
    FROM  user u
    JOIN  linedata l  ON u.id = l.userid
    WHERE  l.timestamp >= '2018-02-28 20:00:00.000'
      AND  l.timestamp  < '2018-11-20 09:20:08.218';
```

Another thing.  You probably want to be able to look up a user by `name`; so add `INDEX(name)`

Oh, what the heck is the `VARCHAR(255)` for `userID`??  Ids are normally integers.

Comment: This covers most of what I was going to suggest. Note, I think the OP included their accurate table structures, it's just that there is no PK in the `linedata` table, and the `id` column there does in fact contain the same value as the `id` column in the `user` table. The `userId` looks like an alternative identifier, for some purpose. Likely, your suggested index of `(userid,timestamp)` could instead be handled by just making a PRIMARY KEY out of `(id,timestamp)`, as a user is unlikely to be allowed to have more than one location at a time.

Comment: What says @WillemRenzema is right. I didn't have a pk for table linedata, but anyway I have created an ai pk called id. And I joined the id of user table(pk ai) with the userId value that now is integer too and matches correctly.

Comment: @Rick James thank you for your answer. I have corrected certain points.. especially the `personId` type. I have generated an integer value that corresponds to the unique `id` of the `user` table now. **What I think that cannot work properly is your query suggestion**, cause I get just one row result that corresponds to just one user. In theory I should get around 21k rows with the concatenation of each timestamp and coordinates. I think you are missing the final `group by u.id`. Am I right? And if I add it the benchmark for get all the data is around **15 secs**. I update the `EXPLAIN` stmt.

Comment: @UgoL - Good start.  But before I go any further, please clarify `personId` versus `userId` -- are they the same?  Do they uniquely identify each user?  Why 255?  The `EXPLAIN` and timing are still bad because of lack if index(es) on linedata; please fix.  (And maybe some other things that Willem or I mentioned.)

Comment: @RickJames yes forgive me for the confusion.. `personId` is `userId`. Let me update the question with an example for show better everything, especially the relationship between `userId` and `id`. Cause I made some changes. What you mean with lack of indexes on linedata? It should be correct I supposed, but I'll show too this part in the update question.

Comment: @RickJames  I have updated the question, let me know if it's clearer now, especially the **255 varchar** for userId in user table. About the index I don't know why cause I have added a **compound index** on `userId` and `timestamp` on linedata table.

Comment: @UgoL - If, _but only if_, the pair `(userId, timestamp)` is unique, then make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`.  Yes, this will further increase performance.

Comment: Did you take a look to the updated question? What about the compound index that I already added? Cause now the benchmark is still hight as time. Around 14 secs.

Comment: @UgoL - To use the composite index, the date constants and expression must be changed; see the first part of my Answer.  Also, please update any more things that are out of date or scattered.  (Example, get the index(es) inside the `CREATE TABLEs`.)

Comment: @RickJames The index is this one in the CREATE TABLE for the linedata table: KEY `id_timestamp_index` (`userId`,`timestamp`). I update the create table also in the question now. And yes, I have changed the date and the expression as you suggested. But I still have high time benchmark.

Comment: @UgoL - Until I see all the changes made in your Question (either by editing existing stuff, or by adding a new version), I have to assume something was not transcribed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184059/discussion-between-ugol-and-rick-james).